# Application Logs Not Flushing

Tags: java, google-app-engine

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

states that

> Application (user/app-generated) logs are periodically flushed while manual and basic scaling instances handle requests; since modules can run on a request a long time, logs may not flush for a while. You can tune the flush settings, or force an immediate flush, using the Logs API.

However I can't find how to flush logs at all. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can force a flush using this the [ApiProxy class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy):

```
import com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy;

ApiProxy.flushLogs();
```